# RStudio: open vignettes in custom PDF viewer

Tags: r, rstudio

When clicking on `pdf` of an R package vignette via the `help` menu tab in RStudio, the vignette always opens in the built in PDF viewer of my system (`Preview` on macOS). However the default PDF viewer of my PC is set to a custom application.

`Sys.getenv()` returns the following

```
R_PDFVIEWER                     /usr/bin/open
```

When calling `/usr/bin/open` manually with a random PDF file from the command line, the custom PDF viewer (which is set as the default one on my system)  is used.

1. Why does RStudio use the built-in PDF viewer and not the system-default?
2. What do I need to change so that RStudio uses the system-default PDF viewer?

Comment: Should work: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200696696-pdf-viewer-of-choice. Did you change the setting in Tools > Global Options > Sweave  > PDF preview?

Comment: Changing this setting has no effect at all - whether I use `System Viewer`, `RStudio Viewer` or `No Preview` -> PDF links are always opened using mac´s Preview.